# Proxy Sale - Affiliate Fraud on Thank You page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversions, affiliate, fraud-detection

I have implemented CPS affiliate sale tracking pixels on thank you page using GTM and tracking sales through GA.

When I checked conversion path in GA, I suspect there might be proxy sales happening on the thank you page.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to find these suspected transactions? If affiliates use bots to refresh the thank you page, then why I see a tracking gap of 3-5 days in affiliate control panel? Is there any escape window? I am searching a support document on usage of cookies in affiliate fraud.

Do I need to do anything through GTM, GA or through Google Webmasters Tools?